# JQ - Denormalize nested object

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I've been trying to convert some JSON to csv and I have the following problem:

I have the following input json:

```
{"id": 100, "a": [{"t" : 1,"c" : 2 }, {"t": 2, "c" : 3 }] }
{"id": 200, "a": [{"t": 2, "c" : 3 }] }
{"id": 300, "a": [{"t": 1, "c" : 3 }] }
```

And I expect the following CSV output:

```
id,t1,t2
100,2,3
200,,3
300,3,
```

Unfortunately JQ doesn't output if one of select has no match.
Example:

```
echo '{ "id": 100,  "a": [{"t" : 1,"c" : 2 }, {"t": 2, "c" : 3 }] }' | jq '{t1: (.a[] | select(.t==1)).c , t2: (.a[] | select(.t==2)).c }'
```

output:

```
{ "t1": 2,  "t2": 3   }
```

but if one of the objects select returns no match it doesn't return at all.
Example:

```
echo '{ "id": 100,  "a": [{"t" : 1,"c" : 2 }] }' | jq '{t1: (.a[] | select(.t==1)).c , t2: (.a[] | select(.t==2)).c }'
```

Expected output:

```
{ "t1": 2,  "t2": null   }
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this with JQ?

EDIT:

Based on a comment made by @peak I found the solution that I was looking for.

```
jq -r '["id","t1","t2"],[.id, (.a[] | select(.t==1)).c//null, (.a[] | select(.t==2)).c//null ]|@csv'
```

The alternative operator does exactly what I was looking for.
[Alternative Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://)

Comment: Please also describe the basic requirements so that others can more readily benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution that does not assume anything about the ordering of the items in the .a array, and easily generalizes to arbitrarily many .t values:

```
# Convert an array of {t, c} to a dictionary:
def tod: map({(.t|tostring): .c}) | add;

["id", "t1", "t2"],   # header
(inputs 
 | (.a | tod) as $dict
 | [.id, (range(1;3) as $i | $dict[$i|tostring]) ])
| @csv
```

#### Command-line options

Use the -n option (because `inputs` is being used), and the -r option (to produce CSV).

Comment: I almost added "Wait for @peak to produce something a third the size" to my answer.

Comment: @peak: Anyway I can fix `jq -r '["id","t1","t2"],[.id, (.a[] | select(.t==1)).c//null, (.a[] | select(.t==2)).c//null ]|@csv' json` to avoid printing header multiple times?

Comment: @Inian - The simplest approach is to use `inputs`.

Comment: @peak thanks for your comment. It helped me find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an absolute mess, but it works:

```
$ cat tmp.json
{"id": 100, "a": [{"t" : 1,"c" : 2 }, {"t": 2, "c" : 3 }] }
{"id": 200, "a": [{"t": 2, "c" : 3 }] }
{"id": 300, "a": [{"t": 1, "c" : 3 }] }
$ cat filter.jq
def t(id):
  .a |
  map({key: "t\(.t)", value: .c}) |
  ({t1:null, t2:null, id:id} | to_entries) + . | from_entries
  ;

inputs |
  map(.id as $id | t($id)) |
  (.[0] | keys) as $hdr |
  ([$hdr] + map(to_entries |map(.value)))[]|
  @csv
$ jq -rn --slurp -f filter.jq tmp.json
"id","t1","t2"
2,3,100
,3,200
3,,300
```

In short, you produce a direct object containing the values from your input, then add it to a "default" object to fill in the missing keys.